# Macro for open balls similar to mathool's DeclarePairedDelimiterX

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, mathtools

I would like to create a macro `\openball[<optional size>]{<radius>}{<center>}` producing

```
\mathrm{B}_{<radius>}^\circ \lparen <center> \rparen
```

if no optional argument is given and

```
\mathrm{B}_{<radius>}^\circ <optional size>\lparen <center> <optional size>\rparen
```

if a size argument is given. So a sample use would be:

```
\openball[\big]{ \varepsilon }{ \tfrac{1}{2} }
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: are you set on the comma? it would be more normal since it is a fixed number of parameters (and definable just with `\newcommand` no internal tricks) if if the syntax was `\openball[size]{radius}{centre}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes sure, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an implementation similar to the one `mathtools` use, implemented using `xparse`.

Update, added that if the radius argument is empty, then `\varepsilon` is used.

Update, now also commented

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\BB{s o m m} {%
  \mathrm{B}
  % add the subscript, _ is special in expl3, so we use \sb. We combine 
  % with a test on #3, if empty use \varepsilon
  \sb{
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#3} {\varepsilon} {#3}
  }
  % if * is active we use \left...\right, modified with proper groups
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup
    \left( #4
      \aftergroup\egroup
    \right)
  }{
    % if no * we look for optional arg which is assumed to be a
    % \big..., if none, just use normal ()'s
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
      ( #4 )
    }{
      % if there is strip the \ from the [] arg, and append l and r to
      % get the proper variants
      \use:c {\cs_to_str:N #2 l} (
      #4
      \use:c {\cs_to_str:N #2 r} )
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
 \[
\BB{s}{b} \BB{}{b}\BB*{2}{\frac12} \BB[\Big]{3}{\sum_i}
 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this one as it seems to be most flexible (and did the job of being my very first introduction into LaTeX3e syntax). Thank you.

Comment: @JohnDorian It only use five macros directly from expl3 (`\ExplSyntaxOn/Off, `\tl_if_blank:nTF,  `\use:c` and `\cs_to_str:N`), the rest if the outward facing interface for normal users from `xparse`.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch two birds with a stone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ball}{t+ s O{} m m}{
  % #1 is the possible +
  % #2 is the possible *
  % #3 is the optional size
  % #4 is the radius
  % #5 is the center
  \mathrm{B}_{#4}\IfBooleanF{#1}{^\circ}
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
   {\paren*{#5}}
   {\paren[#3]{#5}}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\ball{s}{b}
\quad
\ball+{s}{b}
\quad
\ball*{2}{\frac{1}{2}}
\quad
\ball+*{2}{\frac{1}{2}}
\quad
\ball[\Big]{3}{\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Calling `\ball+` will typeset the closed ball.

[image]

If you'd like to denote the closed ball with `\bar{B}`, it's easy: change the line

```
  \mathrm{B}_{#4}\IfBooleanF{#1}{^\circ}
```

into

```
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\bar{\mathrm{B}}}{\mathrm{B}^{\circ}}_{#4}
```

Complete definition

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ball}{t+ s O{} m m}{
  % #1 is the possible +
  % #2 is the possible *
  % #3 is the optional size
  % #4 is the radius
  % #5 is the center
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\bar{\mathrm{B}}}{\mathrm{B}^{\circ}}_{#4}
  \IfBooleanTF{#2}
   {\paren*{#5}}
   {\paren[#3]{#5}}
}
```

The output would be

[image]

A different approach, with a key-value interface; if the radius is not set, it defaults to `\varepsilon`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ball}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { dorian/ball } { #1 }
  % the B
  \bool_if:NTF \l_dorian_ball_open_bool
   { \mathrm{B}\sp{\circ} }
   { \bar{\mathrm{B}} }
  % radius
  \sb{\l_dorian_ball_radius_tl}
  %
  \bool_if:NTF \l_dorian_ball_expand_bool
   { \paren* }
   { \exp_last_unbraced:NNo \paren[\l_dorian_ball_size_tl] }
  {#2}
  \group_end:
}

\bool_new:N \l_dorian_ball_expand_bool
\tl_new:N \l_dorian_ball_size_tl

\keys_define:nn { dorian/ball }
 {
  c .bool_set_inverse:N = \l_dorian_ball_open_bool,
  c .default:n = true,
  c .initial:n = false,
  r .tl_set:N  = \l_dorian_ball_radius_tl,
  r .initial:n = \varepsilon,
  size .code:n =
   \str_if_eq:nnTF { * } { #1 }
    { \bool_set_true:N \l_dorian_ball_expand_bool }
    { \tl_set:Nn \l_dorian_ball_size_tl { #1 } },
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\ball[r=s]{b}
\quad
\ball[c,r=s]{b}
\quad
\ball[size=*,r=2]{\frac{1}{2}}
\quad
\ball[c,size=*,r=2]{\frac{1}{2}}
\quad
\ball[size=\Big]{\frac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot the `\varepsilon` for if the radius is not given ;-)

Comment: @daleif I can't see such a request.

Comment: This is nice. And very simple code. But it will get a little bit more complicated if I decide the closed ball should be typset with a `\bar`, won't it?

Comment: @JohnDorian The change is possible, see edit.

Comment: @egreg I think I interpreted it a little differently, at least using an empty arg is faster than writing `\varepsilon` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand*\openball[3][\relax]{\mathrm{B}^{\circ}_{#2}\mathopen{#1\lparen}#3\mathclose{#1\rparen}}
```

Comment: Just FYI, this does not add the *-feature that `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` does.

Comment: I know. But I don't think it's particularly useful for this open ball syntax. In any case, of course your answer is much more complete.

Comment: I agree, this is perhaps the simplest and most straight-forward solution which deserves an upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the comma-separated syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\radiusandcenter#1{\expandafter\splitatcomma#1\end}%
\def\splitatcomma#1,#2\end{\def\radius{#1}\def\center{#2}}%
\newcommand{\openball}[2][]{%
  \radiusandcenter{#2}%
  \mathrm{B}_{\radius}^\circ\mathopen{#1\lparen}\center\mathclose{#1\rparen}%
}

\begin{document}

\(\openball{\varepsilon,\tfrac{1}{2}}\)

\(\openball[\big]{\varepsilon,\tfrac{1}{2}}\)

\(\openball[\bigg]{\varepsilon,\tfrac{1}{2}}\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your work to save these too braces in the syntax. Also very clever.